# MS Access VBA, not getting results when running DoCmd to find a record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am not a programmer by any means but I am trying to get a small data collection database going.  I need to find a record based on input.  Ive got two criteria that I want it to find, and if both arent found together, it is supposed to create a new record (with both fields filled out to prevent duplication of the pair).  First criteria is that it needs to look for a date.  I figured that one out already, here is the code.

```
Dim Date1 As String
Date1 = Text6.Value

DoCmd.OpenForm "Data", , , "Data![ShiftDate] = #" & Date1 & "#"
```

Works like a charm.  Now, I tried to add the second criteria in.  The second criteria pulls from a listbox, either Day or Night.  Then, it is supposed to search my data fields for that same criteria in a list box on my Data! form.

```
Dim Date1 As String
Dim Shift1 As String

Date1 = Text6.Value
Shift1 = List12.Column(1)
MsgBox Shift1

DoCmd.OpenForm "Data", , , _
   "Data![ShiftDate] = #" & Date1 & "# AND Data![Shift] ='" & Shift1 & "'"
```

the msgbox was just to verify that it is pulling the right words, day or night.  Everything works great, but instead of pulling a record on the right date, and with the right shift, I get blank records.  I tried taking out the first half of the where statement to isolate the shift part and still just cannot get it to find a record.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is `Shift` really stored as text or does the listbox display a text that is associated to a numeric ID? Where do the entries of the listbox come from? Like Day =1, Night = 2

Comment: I had a table for that, but eventually just killed the listbox entirely because it was unneccessary.  Its working now just as textboxes.  Now, the trick is to figure out how to input data into the date and shift field when they are not already created!  If record isnt located, create new one as usual but autofill the two criteria with the inputs used to search...

Comment: Are you control box names the same as your underlying table's field names?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already have a form.

I recommend you trying this: 
Add a button with a click event to the form and add following code to the click event:

`dim rs as dao.recordset 
set rs = currentdb.openrecordset ("SELECT * FROM [yourtable] WHERE ('ShiftDate' = '" & [yourParameter] & "' AND 'Shift' = '" & [your2ndParameter] & "')") 
if rs.eof then
' here NO record is found
currentdb.execute ("INSERT INTO [yourtable] ('ShiftDate', 'Shift') VALUES ('" & [yourParameter] & "', '" & [your2ndParameter] & "')")
else
' here a record is found
endif`

Since your ShiftDate is a date you need to convert your date to a SQL date Format, like this:

```
Function SQLDatum(Datumx) As String
If IsDate(Datumx) Then
    SQLDatum = Format(CDate(Datumx), "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#", vbMonday, _
                      vbFirstFourDays)
  Else
    SQLDatum = ""
End If
End Function
```

Comment: For a simple lookup I would simply use the `DLookup` function and just return the ID (primary key field) if the record.

Comment: DLookup might be easier, but I have learnt the performance of a RS is better.

Answer (score 0):

In your command

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Data", , , "Data![ShiftDate] = #" & Date1 & "# AND ...
```

You open a form `Data` but at the same time you specify a filter by referring  to the form which is being opened with `Data![ShiftDate]`. This is very strange, since the filter must be applied to the data source. I would simply write

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Data", , , "ShiftDate= #" & Date1 & "# AND Shift= '" & Shift1 & "'"
```

by referring to the table columns of the data source (on the left side of `=`).

Note that the column `Shift` must be a text column. If it was some number, you would have to drop the single quotes and pass it a corresponding id.